# Uninitialized Variables in Google Colab

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I am running a CNN architecture in google colab, however, even after initializing my variable as a global variable, I still get the error 'variable not defined'. Is there some other workaround this? Please guide me through an appropriate way to help overcome this.

```
global bits, L_weights

bits_init = bit_level_precision(cond_vals, normal_dist, num_bits, max_w_b_norm)
if model_used == 'normal':
    L_weights_init = xbar_output(bits_init[0],w_inp, w_dim)

elif model_used == 'proposed':
    f_grp_mapping = []
    L_weights_init = xbar_output_prop(bits_init[0],w_inp, w_dim, grouped_cells, f_grp_mapping)

if fix_used == 'none':
    bits = bit_level_precision(cond_vals, new_xbar, num_bits, max_w_b_norm)
    L_weights = xbar_output(bits[0],w_inp, w_dim)
```

Comment: Please do share a complete notebook that reproduces the problem. It's difficult to know from the snippet provided what's going wrong.

Comment: Here is the link to my notebook https://colab.research.google.com/drive/177JbCb0j-7t5D5Hv9moN06hwBpzHND19#scrollTo=UPCd4FHBZ-BJ&uniqifier=2&line=177

Comment: Please share the notebook. Right now, it's private.

Comment: I hope this is accessible. 
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/177JbCb0j-7t5D5Hv9moN06hwBpzHND19

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you open Google colab notebook, try running all cells from 1st cell using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>, this may solve your problem. You may have defined the variable previously in some other cell which worked on another cloud based runtime , when you reopen the notebook all cell elements will be saved but needs to get working on the same cloud based runtime as that of now.